# Connect-redis store don't work with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, socket.io

I have an easy question for someone who use connect-redis.

I want to use it with socket.io with the function `io.set('store', something)`.
I don't know why, when I do

```
var RedisSessionStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
var sessionStore = new RedisSessionStore();

app.use(express.session({
  secret: 'some totally secret key',
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60
  },
  store: sessionStore
}));

//and then I wan't to use the session store for socket.io
io.set('store', sessionStore);
```

It says `Object #<RedisStore> has no method 'subscribe'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`connect-redis` is a Redis-backed session store for Connect/Express, but it's incompatible with the 'store protocol' that `socket.io` uses.

Instead, you need to use the Redis store implementation shipped with `socket.io`:

```
var SocketIoRedisStore = require('socket.io/lib/stores/redis'),
    redis              = require('socket.io/node_modules/redis');
...
io.set('store', new SocketIoRedisStore({
  redisPub    : redis.createClient(),
  redisSub    : redis.createClient(),
  redisClient : redis.createClient()
}));
```

([docs](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO#server))

Comment: Thank you! I was afraid because I thought that I will have to create second set of pub/sub/client, one for socket.io and one for express. Now I see that the `new RedisSessionStore` accept a redis client as an option.

Comment: Does this mean that this line above var RedisSessionStore = require('connect-redis')(express); should be removed from the app.js file or just rename the variable to create the io.set part? and if the var is to be removed, what do you store the express session above as?